# fixed position of a list title, within a container

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I am trying to get the title (h2) of a scrollable list to stay fixed in relation to that window, and that window only.  When I try `position:fixed`, the title is fixed in relation to the scrollable window, but also to the entire page.  How do I get the fixed positioning to apply only to the scrollable list window?

HTML code

```css
.sub-headlines {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  width: 55%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.sub-headlines h2 {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgb(238, 253, 247);
  z-index: 0;
}

.sub-headlines-title {
  position: fixed;
}

.sub-headlines ul {
  overflow: auto;
  list-style: disc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  z-index: -100;
}
```

```html
<div div class="sub-headlines">
  <h2>Recent Headlines in Aging Science</h2>
  <div class="sub-headlines-list">  
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>d</li>
    <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
    <li>g</li>
  </ul> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: absolute;` is the choice for that. It relates to the next higher ancestor which has `position: relative`. Use the `top`/`bottom`/`left`/`right` parameters to position it and/or `width`/`height`(also in percentage values) to define its size if it should be larger than its contents.

Keep in mind that elements with `position: absolute;` (same as `fixed`) don't occupy any space of their own, so they can overlap other elements. To avoid that, you can for example use `padding` settings for the parent element or `margin` for subsequent elements to create empty space behind the absolutely positioned child element.

Comment: the position: absolute worked great.  Adjusting width to 50% gave me good positioning as well.  Thanx.